# Analysis of a simple system consisting of a transformer

Tags: electromagnetism, electronics

Considering a transformer whose second winding is connected to a resistor, such that alternating electric current is induced in the secondary winding by the primary, an attempt of analyzing the secondary circuit yields an impossible result. My naive calculation is as follows: $$V_L = -L\frac{dI}{dt}, \quad I=I_0e^{i\omega t},\quad V_R=IR,\quad V_L+V_R=0 \quad
 =>\quad i\omega LI=IR\quad => \quad i\omega L=R\quad => \quad R=0,\quad L=0$$
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You're missing an applied voltage in your Kichoff's equation. Your results are for if you have no input. However, zero is not the only solution to your calculations, its just one.

Comment: The sign for the voltage across the inductor should be positive, per passive sign convention.

Comment: @Kraig Define applied voltage. The current on the secondary coil causes a voltage drop which may be considered as the applied voltage, as far as my understanding goes.